# Getting coordinates at a given distance along a route in Google Maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

Here is what I want to do

1. Calculate a route from A to B.
2. Place a marker along that route
   at a specified distance from A, and display a street view at that point.

Have experimented with http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js and drawing polylines, but problem is that the distance between points in the routes->overview_path is too far apart causing the polyline to make "shortcuts".

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Don't use the overview path, create a polyline with the points in the route.

Comment: Yeah, tried that too, but in my case the points in the route and in the overview_path are the same....

Comment: A more elegant solution than what? What does your code look like?  Have you seen [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)?

Comment: Wow, well, yes, very helpful indeed! Exactly what I was trying to do.. Much more elegant that messing around with overview_path. THX!